# Spring Security - CAS custom to LDAP integration

Tags: spring-security, ldap, single-sign-on, cas

Initially apologize for the bad english. I'm brazilian and really not have a good english.

I'm using a ldaps for authentication using CAS and the error are a old acquaintance the "PKIX path building failed".

My CAS server certified is self-signed. In this case, are the LDAP server that not relying on the connection?

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I work with CAS and ever I see this message means issue with certificate. Verify if the server of your app has the certiicate in JDK(cacerts). Pay attention, you should import to the correct cacerts. I saw this a lot... people with the same problem because has imported to another jvm.

Qualquer coisa me manda um e-mail =D